# HTML field formatting

Tags: html, css

I have a standard HTML form.

```
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
    Enter Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Enter Email Address:    <input type="text" name="email">
    Enter Message:  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Form">
</form>
```

The problem is that when a value is input that is larger than the field size, upon clicking away, the field skips back to the beginning of the field so the end is cut off.

Is there a way to get it so that the view of the field stays where the carat was?

Comment: that's browser behavior, and not really changeable from anything you can do.

Comment: Make your `<input>`s wide enough to fit most names and e-mail addresses?

Comment: OT: The form elements need `<label>`s to be accessible.

Comment: @MarcB is right. You can, though, use an alternative approach such as expanding the input field when needed by Javascript.

Comment: Yeah I would resize if I could but it would just throw the whole layout of the page out. It's not too big an issue but would of been handy if there was a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a javascript problem (client side), not a PHP one (server side).

You need to do this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" size="10" onblur="if (this.length > 10) {this.dir = 'rtl';} else {this.dir = 'ltr';}">
```

just check what is the proper length to use in order to change the input direction

Comment: @dizzytri99er no problem, glad to help ;) give it a try and mark it as the solution to your question if it works fine for you.

Comment: Such an unorthodox approach, yet brilliant. One correction, though: `if(this.value.length>10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML attribute `size`.